# Name doesn't exist in namespace

Tags: c#, wpf

I refactoring my current project. Currently I am restructuring the folder structure, but I'm getting this error now:

> The name "" does not exist in namespace

I got:

```xaml
<UserControl x:Class="Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem._01_LoadingPlace.DialogWindows.CarDetail.UCDeliveryDetail"
```

and

```xaml
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem._01_LoadingPlace.DialogWindows.CarDetail.Converters"       
xmlns:conv2="clr-namespace:Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem._01_LoadingPlace.ViewAnnouncedVehicles.Converters"
xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem._01_LoadingPlace.DialogWindows.CarDetail.Helpers"
```

```xaml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:IsCurrentLoadingSiteToInvertedValueConverter x:Key="IsCurrentToInverted" />
    <converters:IsCurrentLoadingSiteToVisibilityConverter x:Key="IsCurrentToVisibility" />
    <converters:IsControlWeighingToVisibility x:Key="IsControlWeighToVisibility" />
    <converters:IsWeightResetToVisibility x:Key="IsWeightResetToVisibility" />
    <converters:DeliveryIsLoadedToVisibility x:Key="DeliveryIsLoadedToVisibility" />
    <conv2:EnumWTypeToString x:Key="WeighingTypeToStringConverter" />
    <conv2:BooleanToString x:Key="BooleanToString" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

For example this converter and its header:

```cs
namespace Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem._01_LoadingPlace.DialogWindows.CarDetail.Converters
{
    public class IsWeightResetToVisibility : IValueConverter
```

I think the namespace path is right. Any tips for that? Thanks.

Comment: What sometimes helps when everything seems to be right but you can't compile: Close Visual Studio, delete all bin and obj folders, open Visual Studio and rebuild all.

Comment: Is that even valid ``_01_LoadingPlace``, can it start with ``_``?

Comment: Are you saying that the error actually shows an empty pair of quotes and nothing after the word "namespace"?

Comment: RandRandom - yes that is valid. Even is i create new converter i got in namespace _loadingPlace :)

Comment: @DanielCapek If that doesn't work, comment out all usages of the classes that don't work, compile and comment them in again.

Comment: @JLRishe Nope. I dont want to copy all path, so i just write in "" :D In all these resources i get error the name does not exist in namespace "path"...

Comment: @DanielCapek Can you show us at least one of the full errors, not one with all the information removed?

Comment: @JLRishe For example: Severity Code Description Project Project Rank File Column Category Source Suppression State Line Tool
Error  The name "IsWeightResetToVisibility" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem._01_LoadingPlace.DialogWindows.CarDetail.Converters". Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem 6 C:\Users\n029330\Desktop\Z05 MES\DcpBranch\dcp-[M051602-399]-Z05-MES-Klient-v1.2-branch\Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem\01_LoadingPlace\DialogWindows\CarDetail\UCDeliveryDetail.xaml 9  Build  18

Comment: The line ``Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem._01_LoadingPlace.D‌​ialogWindows.CarDeta‌​il.Converters`` has invisible characters in ``DialogWindow`` between the ``D`` and the ``i``.

Comment: @RandRandom What invisible characters? o.o

Comment: @DanielCapek give me some minutes I am preparing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your posted msg from the comments:

> Severity Code Description Project Project Rank File Column Category
>   Source Suppression State Line Tool Error The name
>   "IsWeightResetToVisibility" does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem._01_LoadingPlace.D‌​ialogWindows.CarDeta‌​il.Converters".
>   Z05.‌​MES.WPF.WeighingSyst‌​em 6 C:\Users\n02933‌​0\Desktop\Z05
>   MES\DcpBranch\dcp-[M051602-399]-Z05-MES-Klient-v1.2-branch\Z‌​05.MES.WPF.WeighingS‌​ystem\01_LoadingPlac‌​e\DialogWindows\CarD‌​etail\UCDeliveryDeta‌​il.xaml
>   9 Build 18

There are multiple invis characters in your namespace as you can see here:
[image]

The invis characters are in

- `DialogWindows` - between the `D` and `i`
- `CarD‌​etail` - between the `a` and `i`

Here is your fixed namespace:

```
clr-namespace:Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem._01_LoadingPlace.DialogWindows.CarDetail.Converters
```

Comment: Still the same problem >x

Comment: @DanielCapek And you checked every single ``XAML`` of your project if any of the namespaces has any invalid characters?

Comment: problems are only in two xamls, which i have checked. So yes i checked every single xaml file.

Comment: @DanielCapek Can you pls again post the complete error msg you are getting.

Comment: @DanielCapek you can give that regex: ``clr-namespace:.+[\x00-\x1f]|[\x81\x8d\x8d\x8f\x90\x9d\xa0\u2060\uFEFF]`` a try and search in your whole solution, dont forget to activate regex in the find dialog.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project Project Rank File Column Category Source Suppression State Line Tool
Error  The type 'convs:BooleanToString' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem 6 C:\Users\n029330\Desktop\Z05 MES\DcpBranch\dcp-[M051602-399]-Z05-MES-Klient-v1.2-branch\Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem\01_LoadingPlace\DialogWindows\CarDetail\UCDeliveryDetail.xaml 10  Build  22

Comment: Severity Code Description Project Project Rank File Column Category Source Suppression State Line Tool
Error  The name "IsCurrentLoadingSiteToVisibilityConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem._01_LoadingPlace.DialogWindows.CarDetail.Converters". Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem 6 C:\Users\n029330\Desktop\Z05 MES\DcpBranch\dcp-[M051602-399]-Z05-MES-Klient-v1.2-branch\Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem\01_LoadingPlace\DialogWindows\CarDetail\UCDeliveryDetail.xaml 9  Build  17

Comment: Everything the same invis characters all over the place, not only the namespaces contains them also your file paths contains them. You Need to clean those or you will have problems again and again.

Comment: I try to check all refactored folders and paths and try to clear them.

Comment: I fixed all my errors. Repaired all paths. :) But anyway, thanks for your help and time :)

Comment: @DanielCapek - dont really get the "But anyway" since I was the one pointing you to the invis chars in the first place so that you could fix all your paths, so.... maybe accept my answer?